# Trouble getting information from JSON file

Tags: python, json

Small example of my JSON file:

```
{
        "UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA": {
            "channel statistics": {
                "viewCount": "3754404",
                "subscriberCount": "76900",
                "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
                "videoCount": "152"
            },
            "video_data": {
                "cHDiiE0LmIA": {
                    "publishedAt": "2021-12-08T15:15:01Z",
                    "channelId": "UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA",
                    "title": "How to execute a Program or System Command from Python #Shorts",
                    "description": "This video shows how to run a system command from Python and how to execute another program.\n\n\u2b50  Join Our Discord : https://discord.gg/FHMg9tKFSN\n\nIf you enjoyed this video, please subscribe to the channel:\n\u25b6\ufe0f : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA?sub_confirmation=1\n\nWe go over the following options:\nsubprocess.run()\nos.system()\nsubprocess.Popen()\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ CONNECT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\ud83d\udda5\ufe0f Website: https://www.python-engineer.com\n\ud83d\udc26 Twitter - https://twitter.com/python_engineer\n\u2709\ufe0f Newsletter - https://www.python-engineer.com/newsletter\n\ud83d\udcf8 Instagram - https://www.instagram.com/patloeber\n\ud83e\uddbe Discord: https://discord.gg/FHMg9tKFSN\n\u25b6\ufe0f  Subscribe: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA?sub_confirmation=1\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SUPPORT ME  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\ud83c\udd7f Patreon - https://www.patreon.com/patrickloeber\n\n#Python",
                    "thumbnails": {
                        "default": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cHDiiE0LmIA/default.jpg",
                            "width": 120,
                            "height": 90
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cHDiiE0LmIA/mqdefault.jpg",
                            "width": 320,
                            "height": 180
                        },
                        "high": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cHDiiE0LmIA/hqdefault.jpg",
                            "width": 480,
                            "height": 360
                        }
                    },
                    "channelTitle": "Python Engineer",
                    "tags": [
                        "Python"
                    ],
                    "categoryId": "27",
                    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
                    "localized": {
                        "title": "How to execute a Program or System Command from Python #Shorts",
                        "description": "This video shows how to run a system command from Python and how to execute another program.\n\n\u2b50  Join Our Discord : https://discord.gg/FHMg9tKFSN\n\nIf you enjoyed this video, please subscribe to the channel:\n\u25b6\ufe0f : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA?sub_confirmation=1\n\nWe go over the following options:\nsubprocess.run()\nos.system()\nsubprocess.Popen()\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ CONNECT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\ud83d\udda5\ufe0f Website: https://www.python-engineer.com\n\ud83d\udc26 Twitter - https://twitter.com/python_engineer\n\u2709\ufe0f Newsletter - https://www.python-engineer.com/newsletter\n\ud83d\udcf8 Instagram - https://www.instagram.com/patloeber\n\ud83e\uddbe Discord: https://discord.gg/FHMg9tKFSN\n\u25b6\ufe0f  Subscribe: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA?sub_confirmation=1\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SUPPORT ME  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\ud83c\udd7f Patreon - https://www.patreon.com/patrickloeber\n\n#Python"
                    },
                    "defaultAudioLanguage": "en",
                    "viewCount": "353",
                    "likeCount": "34",
                    "dislikeCount": "2",
                    "favoriteCount": "0",
                    "commentCount": "4",
                    "duration": "PT45S",
                    "dimension": "2d",
                    "definition": "hd",
                    "caption": "false",
                    "licensedContent": true,
                    "contentRating": {},
                    "projection": "rectangular"
                },
                "YIUk2rvDxp0": {
                    "publishedAt": "2021-11-19T13:00:27Z",
                    "channelId": "UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA",
                    "title": "Master Pattern Matching In 5 Minutes | All Options | Python 3.10",
                    "description": "Master the new Pattern Matching Feature in this Python 3.10 tutorial. We have a look at all the different code syntax options.\n\nGet my Free NumPy Handbook:\nhttps://www.python-engineer.com/numpybook\n\n\u2705 Write cleaner code with Sourcery, instant refactoring suggestions in VS Code & PyCharm: https://sourcery.ai/?utm_source=youtube&utm_campaign=pythonengineer *\n\n\ud83e\ude81 Code faster with Kite, AI-powered autocomplete that integrates into VS Code:\nhttps://www.kite.com/get-kite/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=youtube&utm_campaign=pythonengineer&utm_content=description-only *\n\n\u2b50  Join Our Discord : https://discord.gg/FHMg9tKFSN\n\n\ud83d\udcd3 ML Notebooks available on Patreon:\nhttps://www.patreon.com/patrickloeber\n\nIf you enjoyed this video, please subscribe to the channel:\n\u25b6\ufe0f : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA?sub_confirmation=1\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ CONNECT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\ud83d\udda5\ufe0f Website: https://www.python-engineer.com\n\ud83d\udc26 Twitter - https://twitter.com/python_engineer\n\u2709\ufe0f Newsletter - https://www.python-engineer.com/newsletter\n\ud83d\udcf8 Instagram - https://www.instagram.com/patloeber\n\ud83e\uddbe Discord: https://discord.gg/FHMg9tKFSN\n\u25b6\ufe0f  Subscribe: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA?sub_confirmation=1\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SUPPORT ME  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\ud83c\udd7f Patreon - https://www.patreon.com/patrickloeber\n\n#Python\n\nTimeline:\n00:00 - Intro\n00:28 - 1 Basic Syntax\n00:51 - 2 Multiple Matches\n00:58 - 3 No Fall Through\n01:22 - 4 Wildcard\n01:37 - 5 Unpacking and Variable Binding\n01:56 - 6 Patterns and Classes\n02:11 - 7 Patterns With Positional Parameters\n02:27 - 8 Nested Patterns\n02:40 - 9 Complex Patterns and the Wildcard\n02:57 - 10 Guard\n03:07 - 11 More on Sequences\n03:32 - 12 Mapping Patterns\n03:55 - 13 Match with Enum\n04:03 - 14 Bind Subpatterns with as\n04:21 - Final Note\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n* This is an affiliate link. By clicking on it you will not have any additional costs, instead you will support me and my project. Thank you so much for the support! \ud83d\ude4f",
                    "thumbnails": {
                        "default": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YIUk2rvDxp0/default.jpg",
                            "width": 120,
                            "height": 90
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YIUk2rvDxp0/mqdefault.jpg",
                            "width": 320,
                            "height": 180
                        },
                        "high": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YIUk2rvDxp0/hqdefault.jpg",
                            "width": 480,
                            "height": 360
                        },
                        "standard": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YIUk2rvDxp0/sddefault.jpg",
                            "width": 640,
                            "height": 480
                        },
                        "maxres": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YIUk2rvDxp0/maxresdefault.jpg",
                            "width": 1280,
                            "height": 720
                        }
                    },
                    "channelTitle": "Python Engineer",
                    "tags": [
                        "Python"
                    ],
                    "categoryId": "27",
                    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
                    "localized": {
                        "title": "Master Pattern Matching In 5 Minutes | All Options | Python 3.10",
                        "description": "Master the new Pattern Matching Feature in this Python 3.10 tutorial. We have a look at all the different code syntax options.\n\nGet my Free NumPy Handbook:\nhttps://www.python-engineer.com/numpybook\n\n\u2705 Write cleaner code with Sourcery, instant refactoring suggestions in VS Code & PyCharm: https://sourcery.ai/?utm_source=youtube&utm_campaign=pythonengineer *\n\n\ud83e\ude81 Code faster with Kite, AI-powered autocomplete that integrates into VS Code:\nhttps://www.kite.com/get-kite/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=youtube&utm_campaign=pythonengineer&utm_content=description-only *\n\n\u2b50  Join Our Discord : https://discord.gg/FHMg9tKFSN\n\n\ud83d\udcd3 ML Notebooks available on Patreon:\nhttps://www.patreon.com/patrickloeber\n\nIf you enjoyed this video, please subscribe to the channel:\n\u25b6\ufe0f : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA?sub_confirmation=1\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ CONNECT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\ud83d\udda5\ufe0f Website: https://www.python-engineer.com\n\ud83d\udc26 Twitter - https://twitter.com/python_engineer\n\u2709\ufe0f Newsletter - https://www.python-engineer.com/newsletter\n\ud83d\udcf8 Instagram - https://www.instagram.com/patloeber\n\ud83e\uddbe Discord: https://discord.gg/FHMg9tKFSN\n\u25b6\ufe0f  Subscribe: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbXgNpp0jedKWcQiULLbDTA?sub_confirmation=1\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SUPPORT ME  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n\ud83c\udd7f Patreon - https://www.patreon.com/patrickloeber\n\n#Python\n\nTimeline:\n00:00 - Intro\n00:28 - 1 Basic Syntax\n00:51 - 2 Multiple Matches\n00:58 - 3 No Fall Through\n01:22 - 4 Wildcard\n01:37 - 5 Unpacking and Variable Binding\n01:56 - 6 Patterns and Classes\n02:11 - 7 Patterns With Positional Parameters\n02:27 - 8 Nested Patterns\n02:40 - 9 Complex Patterns and the Wildcard\n02:57 - 10 Guard\n03:07 - 11 More on Sequences\n03:32 - 12 Mapping Patterns\n03:55 - 13 Match with Enum\n04:03 - 14 Bind Subpatterns with as\n04:21 - Final Note\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n* This is an affiliate link. By clicking on it you will not have any additional costs, instead you will support me and my project. Thank you so much for the support! \ud83d\ude4f"
                    },
                    "defaultAudioLanguage": "en",
                    "viewCount": "5723",
                    "likeCount": "309",
                    "dislikeCount": "4",
                    "favoriteCount": "0",
                    "commentCount": "29",
                    "duration": "PT4M51S",
                    "dimension": "2d",
                    "definition": "hd",
                    "caption": "false",
                    "licensedContent": true,
                    "contentRating": {},
                    "projection": "rectangular"
                },
```

(It keeps going following the same pattern)

After loading the file to colab (working on google colab):

```
import json

file = 'python_engineer.json'
data = None
with open(file, 'r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

channel_id, stats = data.popitem()
channel_stats = stats['channel statistics']
video_stats = stats['video_data']
```

Now I try to get some information from the JSON file to work with with Pandas:

```
# Video statistics
sorted_vids = sorted(video_stats.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[1]['viewCount']), reverse=True)
stats = []
for vid in sorted_vids:
  video_id = vid[0]
  video_title = vid[1]['title']
  video_view_cnt = vid[1]['viewCount']
  video_likes = vid[1]['likeCount']
  video_dislikes = vid[1]['dislikeCount']
  video_comments = vid[1]['commentCount']
  video_time = vid[1]['duration']
  video_date = vid[1]['publishedAt']
  video_tags = vid[1]['tags']
  stats.append([video_title, video_view_cnt, video_likes, video_dislikes, video_comments, video_time, video_date,video_tags])

stats
```

After I call `stats`, so it prints what I got, it throws an error. I have no idea why its happening. All it says is: `KeyError: 'tags'`, on the following line:

```
video_tags = vid[1]['tags']
```

I have tried in many different ways to get the video tags but it always gives me that error. Maybe because **tags** is a list? I have tried to work arround that but nothing worked.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This doesn't throw an error for me. Instead it prints `[['Master Pattern Matching In 5 Minutes | All Options | Python 3.10',
  '5723',
  '309',
  '4',
  '29',
  'PT4M51S',
  '2021-11-19T13:00:27Z',
  ['Python']],
 ['How to execute a Program or System Command from Python #Shorts',
  '353',
  '34',
  '2',
  '4',
  'PT45S',
  '2021-12-08T15:15:01Z',
  ['Python']]]`

Comment: Can't reproduce this... Is it possible the shape of the file or JSON you parse is not the same as the one you have pasted here? Have you tried running this in another environment than Google Collab?